# How does diet affect OCD?

Tags: clinical-psychology, feeding

**Background:** I have read that caffeine is not a good drink for sufferers of anxiety disorders. This is common sense given that it may increase agitation.
I noticed when I started a low carb diet that my OCD became somewhat less intense. I think that this happened simply because I was *too tired, physically and mentally*. I couldn't even concentrate on studying.

**How does diet affect engaging in OCD?**